# Using for next loop step 50 php?

Tags: php

I want steps for using for next loop.

On a vb or vb.net

```
for i=0 to 1000 STEP 50
....
next
```

How can I use this code in php?

Comment: read the manual `for` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php or some book. this is the basic you must know before starting any code.

Comment: you have to learn how to google `for in php` before ask on stackoverflow.com

Comment: You must read the faq [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 1000; $i += 50)
{
    // Your code...
}
```

It is wise to read [PHP `for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) for more details.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote? May I please know, I am ready to update my answer.

Comment: There are some trolls, that actually think, that you should not answer such questions or smth.

Comment: OKay, like that... :) Thanks.

Comment: @bansi: But he's answering a question, not asking.

Comment: @PraveenKumar sry, wrong box, deleted the comment

Comment: thanks for help. i set this answer true 5 mins later.